# SED - HTML-encode between specific tags in XML file

Tags: xml, sed, html-encode

I´m currently working on a short SED script that needs to HTML-encode parts of an XML-file. The script currently looks like this:

```
sed.exe "/<messageData>/,/<\/messageData>/ {/<messageData>/b;/<\/messageData>/b; s/</\&lt;/g; s/>/\&gt;/g; }" %1 >%2
```

So basically, replace all < and > with < and > , between the  and  tags.

This script works perfectly well with pretty printed XML, that is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Messages>
    <messageData>
        <test>DATA</test>
    </messageData>
</Messages>
```

comes out as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Messages>
    <messageData>
        &lt;test&gt;DATA&lt;/test&gt;
    </messageData>
</Messages>
```

which is what I need. My issue is that the files I need process is not pretty printed, everything is on a single line, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Messages><messageData><test>DATA</test></messageData></Messages>
```

And with this format, the script no longer works. 
Would it be possibly to modify my script to work with both formats?

Please note that I´m not able to affect the output format, and that SED is the scripting engine to be used.

I guess I could just create another SED script that would insert a line-break after each > in the file, and after that run the script that I have created now. However I´m guessing that would not be very efficient performance wise (two passes over each file).

Any suggestions?

Regards
Daniel

Comment: what did your research here on SO tell you about sed and xml? Good luck.

Comment: Like I said in the original post, using SED or not isn´t my choice to make.

Comment: @Daniel, then tell whoever that choice is to make to make it. Using sed or regexps in general to work with XML is a really bad idea. There is a reason why XML-specific tools exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone happens to stumble on the same issue, this is how we solved it. I know it´s not pretty, be it will have to do until we can use a better solution.

```
sed.exe -i "s/\(>\)\(<\)/\1\n\2/g" %1
sed.exe "/<messageData>/,/<\/messageData>/ {/<messageData>/b;/<\/messageData>/b; s/</\&lt;/g; s/>/\&gt;/g; }" %1 >%2
```

Comment: sed is never pretty but I use it all the time ;-). If you are concerned with processing time, you should be able to chain the two sed's together with a pipe to reduce the time for each file. Finally,  you can accept your own answer and get some additional rep points. Good luck.